# Mudar cor de link após usuário scrollar para baixo

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando modificar um código que já funciona muito bem. Tenho este menu:

```
<div id = "menu" > 


    <a href = "index.html"> <img src = "images/logo.png" style = "padding-left: 5%; padding-top: 1%;"> </a>

    <ul id = "lista">
    <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "aboutus.html"> <padding left> SOBRE O INSTITUTO </a></li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "pessoas.html"> PESSOAS</a> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "universidadefour.html"> UNIVERSIDADE FOUR </a> 
            <ul>
                 <a href = "programaprolider.html"> <li> PROGRAMA PROLÍDER </li> </a> 
                 <a href = "universidadefour.html#escolapolitica"> <li> ESCOLA DE POLÍTICA </li> </a> 
                 <a href = "universidadefour.html#escolaempreendedorismo"> <li> ESCOLA DE EMPREENDEDORISMO </li> </a> 
            </ul> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "comunidadefour.html"> <padding left> COMUNIDADE FOUR </a>
            <ul>
                 <a href = "comunidadefour.html"> <li> A COMUNIDADE FOUR</li> </a>
                 <a href = "comunidade.html"> <li> FELLOWS </li> </a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "foursummit.html"> FOUR SUMMIT </a> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "trabalheconosco.html"> VAGAS ABERTAS</a> </li>
        <li style = "display: inline-block;"> <a href = "en-index.html"> EN </a> <span style = "color: white;"> |</span> <a href = "index.html"> BR </a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Este menu, no padrão, não tem background-color, mas quando o usuário desliza pelo site a cor de fundo muda:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}
```

Eu gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa para mudar a cor dos links de branco para preto após o usuário scrollar o site. Como consigo fazer isso?

Comment: Que tal uma classe CSS para cada estado desses?

Answer (score 0):

Só adicionar o seguinte trecho de códico a sua função scroll:

```
document.ElementsByTagName("li").style.color = "black"
```

Comment: Não funcionou... será que eu fiz alguma coisa errada?

 window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

 function scrollFunction() {
   if (document.body.scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  document.getElementsByTagName("li").style.color = "black";
   } else {
  document.getElementById("menu").style.backgroundColor = "";
  document.getElementsByTagName("li").style.color = "";
   }
 }

Comment: Sim, está errado, o scrollTop está deprecado, aqui explica melhor como você deve usar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19635188/why-is-body-scrolltop-deprecated